# Increase performance of thread pool (C++, pthreads)

Tags: c++, pthreads

My application has a main thread that assigns tasks to a number of worker threads. The communication pattern is the following:

The thread function (work is a function pointer here):

```
while(true) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    while(!work)
        pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex); // wait for work...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

    work();

    pthread_barrier_wait(barrier); /*all threads must finish their work*/
    if(thread_id == 0) {
        work = NULL;
        pthread_cond_signal(cond); /*tell the main thread that the work is done*/
    }
    pthread_barrier_wait(barrier); /* make sure that none of the other worker
                                   threads is already waiting on condition again...*/
}
```

In the main thread (the function that assigns a task to the worker threads):

```
pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
work = func;
pthread_cond_broadcast(cond); // tell the worker threads to start...
while(work)
    pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex); // ...and wait for them to finish
pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
```

I did not use a queue here, because there can only be one task at a time and the main thread has to wait for the task to finish. The pattern works fine, but with poor performance. The problem is that tasks will be assigned very often while performing a single task is quite fast. Therefore the threads will suspend and wait on the condition very often. I would like to reduce the number of calls of pthread_mutex_(un)lock, phread_cond_wait and pthread_barrier, but I do not see how this could be done.

Comment: can you explain what task is being shared? maybe the task itself doesn't improve from running it through multiple threads

Comment: Perhaps batch up your tasks, and run them in groups, rather than one at a time?

Comment: I develop a little library for linear algebra computations. The tasks beeing shared are vector operations like addition, subtraction, dot products etc. I have to run one task at a time, because I do not know what operations the user of the library will perform, but the performance of these operations increases significantly when I use threads. Edit: The performance of the code above is not really bad, but not as good as using OpenMP for example (I want to compare both techniques).

Comment: Is it critical that all threads *start* a task at the same time? It seems to me that you could remove the second barrier.

Comment: The second barrier ensures that only the main thread is waiting on the condition variable and and is thus woken up by thread 0. Otherwise one of the other worker threads could already be waiting on the condition again.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one task at a time.

You don't need scheduling.  You don't need threads.  You can get rid of the locking.

Comment: I do need threads. The one task itself is distributed to several threads and it benefits from that. Please see my comment above.

Comment: @cthl then use [`<future>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/future) instead. a [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) call probably makes more sense for you than raw pthreads